# How to solve this problem in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo

When I upload my package in Odoo 10 the problem is:

```
File "/home/nisus/odoo10/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 248, in _check_model
    raise ValidationError(_('Invalid model name %r in action definition.') % action.res_model)
ParseError: "Invalid model name u'myconferences.myconf' in action definition.
None" while parsing /home/nisus/odoo10/odoo-dev/odoo/addons/kugan_one/views/views.xml:5, near
<act_window id="action_myconference" name="Manage Conferences" res_model="myconferences.myconf"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your package in Odoo 10:

`res_model="myconferences.myconf"` : This class of object is not created or maybe you cannot add a custom addons path like:

1. `./odoo-bin --addons-path=addons,custom_addons  -d custom_db`
2. You must check that this class is in your module:

   ```
   class MyconferencesMyconf(models.TransientModel):
       _name = 'myconferences.myconf'
   ```